# Can only iterate controls from first TabItem of a TabControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, tabitem

I am a beginner of wpf. I am going get numbers of buttons from two tabs. It should be 5. However, I can only get the two buttons from the first tab.

I have tried to switch to the tab2, then no buttons can be found.

**Do you know how I can get all the controls from all tabs?**  I am going to bind events to all canvas and buttons in each tab.

**Here is my MainWindow:**

```
<TabControl Name="tabMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- this is the header template-->
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Header}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyTabItem}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Content}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyTabItemCtrl}" >
                            <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=PosX}" />
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=PosY}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btns = UIHelper.FindVisualChildren<Button>(tabMain).ToList();
    // btns == 2
}
```

**ViewModels:**

```
public sealed class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyTabItem> Tabs { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<MyTabItem>();

        ObservableCollection<MyTabItemCtrl> ct1 = new ObservableCollection<MyTabItemCtrl>();
        ct1.Add(new MyTabItemCtrl { Name = "aaa", Age = 5, PosX=10, PosY=10 });
        ct1.Add(new MyTabItemCtrl { Name = "bbb", Age = 5, PosX = 50, PosY = 10 });

        ObservableCollection<MyTabItemCtrl> ct2 = new ObservableCollection<MyTabItemCtrl>();
        ct2.Add(new MyTabItemCtrl { Name = "aaa", Age = 6, PosX = 10, PosY = 10 });
        ct2.Add(new MyTabItemCtrl { Name = "bbb", Age = 6, PosX = 55, PosY = 10 });
        ct2.Add(new MyTabItemCtrl { Name = "ccc", Age = 6, PosX = 100, PosY = 10 });

        Tabs.Add(new MyTabItem { Header = "One", Content = ct1 });
        Tabs.Add(new MyTabItem { Header = "Two", Content = ct2 });
    }
}
public sealed class MyTabItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyTabItemCtrl> Content { get; set; }
}

public sealed class MyTabItemCtrl
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public double PosX { get; set; }
    public double PosY { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the currently visible `TabItem` is loaded into the visual tree so you won't be able to use your `UIHelper.FindVisualChildren` method to find any elements that is not currently visible.

When you switch away from a tab, its content are unloaded from the visual tree. So these `Buttons` don't really exist when another tab is selected.

A `ContentTemplate` is just a *template*. It has to be realized before any actual `Button` elements are created and added to the visual tree.

Comment: Thank you. So you mean I need to realize the ContentTemplate first. Do you know how to make it?

Comment: Select the tab?